# Effect attenuation with adjustment

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, genetics

Typically in genetic studies, sensitivity analyses are used to quantify how estimates of genetic effects are affected by adjusting for additional covariates $Z$. So we have separate regressions for a phenotype $Y$, covariates $X$, and $Z$, and variants $g_k$ indexed by $k$ like:
$$Y  =  X\beta_0 + g_k\gamma_{0,k} + \varepsilon_0 $$
$$Y  =  X\beta_1 + Z\alpha_1 + g_k\gamma_{1,k} + \varepsilon_1 $$
So we may be interested in the relationship between $\gamma_{0,k}$, and $\gamma_{1,k}$ for each variant $k$, as well as the average relationship across $\vec\gamma_0$ and $\vec\gamma_{1}$. To obtain an estimate of the 'average effect ratio' $\rho_Z$, one could fit
$$\hat\gamma_{1} = \hat\gamma_0\rho_Z + \varepsilon_\gamma$$
(Note that we are forcing the intercept to be zero.)

Let's assume that the data generating mechanism is multivariate normal for X, Y and Z, that $g_k$ are independent, while
$$Y  =  X\beta_1 + Z\alpha_1 + G\gamma_1 + \varepsilon_3, $$ and
$$Z  =  X\beta_2 + G\gamma_2 + \varepsilon_2 $$
I have two questions. One, is there a closed form formula for $\rho_z$ depending on phenotypic or genetic correlations between X, Y, and Z? Two, is there a closed form standard error for $\hat \rho_Z$?